# Как в IIB правильно сделать запрос soap и получить ответ?

Tags: ibm

Есть сервис WSDL http://web.cse.ru/1c/ws/Web1C.1cws?wsdl
Как по средством ibm integration bus сделать правильный запрос и получить ответ при вызове метода ping.
Я делаю для теста следующее:
Добавлял static library с этим WSDL файлом, далее
HTTP Input Node, потом пробовал делать Mapping Node, далее SOAP request NODE, в котором указан этот WSDL. Делал всё в debag мод с брэк поинтами, чтобы смотреть какие ответы идут. Но при любых моих действиях я ни как не могу добиться моей цели: сделать запрос к этому soap сервису, чтобы банально получить ответ от функции ping.
Может кто помочь?

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил.
Сделал перед запросом esql compute и добавил вызываемой функции
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.ns:Ping = '';
и получил то что хотел!)